# Is there a service or API option to wrap Puppeteer screenshot with a device frame like Chrome dev console does?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Puppeteer 4, Ubuntu 20.04. In the dev console of Chrome, there is an option to "show device frame", which wraps the responsive emulator with a generic mobile outline.

Is there any equivalent of this for Puppeteer screenshots? I would have thought it would be a popular request, but I have been through all the third party links and have not found one.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such wrapper that supports adding the frames around puppeteer screenshots, but it is easy to achieve it with [node-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images) npm package if you have the device frames as transparent png file. E.g.: `images('iPhone_5_portrait.png').draw(images('wikipedia.png').size(320), 130, 220).save('output.jpg')` It is a good idea for a new package.