# Puppeteer: How to capture a screenshot with device frame?

Tags: puppeteer, screenshot, emulation, mobile-devices

*Note: I am asking here a adapted version of this [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600943/is-there-a-service-or-api-option-to-wrap-puppeteer-screenshot-with-a-device-fram).*

When using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), it's easy to produce screenshots. It's even their first example, and it works fine on my web app:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6']; //iPhone 5/SE does not work

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://web.replayer.app', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'replayer-app.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This produces a nice screenshot, but without device frame.

[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

If I try to use one of the device names, that do produce a visual device frame in Google Chrome, like iPhone5/SE, I get

```
C:\Users\masu\Documents\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1500
            this.setViewport(options.viewport),
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'viewport')
    at Page.emulate (C:\Users\masu\Documents\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1500:38)
    at C:\Users\masu\Documents\puppeteer-question.js:7:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

However, since it's a web app, I would like to have the screen shot a device frame around it.

**How to use and capture a screenshot from an emulated device with a viewport?**

Comment: How do I reduce the image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the cause of the issue?**

I. You get this error because you are emulating the desired device with the wrong name. Even if DevTools UI names it "iPhone 5/SE" in reality DevTools Protocol only knows either "iPhone 5" or "iPhone SE" (you can give a try to give any false strings here, like "iPhone 2000", you will end up with the very same error msg). The available and valid device names are listed in [DeviceDescriptors.ts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/DeviceDescriptors.ts) on Github.

II. Since the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600943/is-there-a-service-or-api-option-to-wrap-puppeteer-screenshot-with-a-device-fram) was asked the situation is still the same: you cannot do a screenshot of the page with the device frames in puppeteer. Simply because those frames are part of the DevTools UI while Puppeteer is a high-level API to control Chrome over the DevTools Protocol: one is related to its frontend the other to its backend functionalities.

**How you can proceed?**

- Implement the functionality in Node yourself. As I mentioned in the other post: it is easy to achieve it with [node-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images) npm package if you have the device frames as transparent png file. E.g.: `images('iPhone_5_portrait.png').draw(images('wikipedia.png').size(320), 130, 220).save('output.jpg')`.
- Raise a feature request on [Puppeteer's GitHub](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues) however it is not likely they plan to go this way (see point II. above).

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I did not want to scrape the device frame images from just somewhere, so did not implement your solution yet. For now, I am creating the images, that should have the device frame, with the DevTools by hand. It's only a few, thus acceptable.

Comment: I explicitly tried "iPhone5/SE" because it's one of the only few phone devices, that actually produce a visual device frame with the DevTools. I hoped, the reason for the missing frames was the used device name.

Comment: yeah. it was only coincidental. _Moto G4_ is one of the others that still has a device frame in emulation mode. it seems they stopped creating the frame visuals for the later models.

Comment: The DeviceDescriptors.ts link returns a 404 on GitHub now. Device names are available on their API docs page at: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.knowndevices